# How to get a number at the end of a string followed by this character `:` using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get a number (integer) at the end of a string followed by this character `:`.

Basically:

`qwe-tyu-iop[-zxc:10  //result  should be 10`

`::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:10  //result  should be 10`

`::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:10.10  //result  should be undefined`

`::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:abc  //result  should be undefined`

`::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:afdf10  //result  should be undefined`

Comment: [`.*:(\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/TDicCU/3) ?

Comment: @Gurman Please post it as answer its correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
inputStr.split(":").pop();
```

Example

```js
function getValue( input )
{
    var value = input.split(":").pop(); 
    return parseInt( value ) == value ? value : "undefined"; 
}

console.log( getValue( "qwe-tyu-iop[-zxc:10" ) );
console.log( getValue( "::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:10" ) );
console.log( getValue( "::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:10.10" ) );
console.log( getValue( "::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:abc" ) );
console.log( getValue( "::qwe-ty:u-iop[-zxc:afdf10" ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach. Get the index of the last `:` and get that part from the string. If it is not a number, `parseInt` will give you `NaN`

```js
const str = '::qwe-tyu-iop[-zxc:10';
const number = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);
console.log(Number.parseInt(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

"qwe-tyu-iop[-zxc:10".match(/:?\d+$/);  // [":10"]

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `regex` as well as using pure `JavaScript`.

Below are both options:

**Using regex**

```
const regex = /:(\d+)$/gm;
const str = `qwe-tyu-iop[-zxc:10`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    console.log(`Found match --->  ${m[1]}`);
}
```

**Using JavaScript only**

```
const input = 'qwe-tyu-iop[-zxc:10';
const value = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);
console.log(Number.parseInt(value) == value ? value : "undefined");
```